# Dagger dosn't let me use two objects of the same type in a single class

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I have this `AppModule` class that contains three functions:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
static FirebaseFirestore provideFirebaseFirestore() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
}

@Singleton
@Provides
static CollectionReference provideUsersCollRef(FirebaseFirestore db) {
    return db.collection("users");
}

@Singleton
@Provides
static CollectionReference provideBarsCollRef(FirebaseFirestore db) {
    return db.collection("bars");
}
```

I've read that I can use some kind of naming but I didn't find any way to solve this. Beside that, how can I differentiate in my fragment code which one of those reference I inject? Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit:**

```
@Inject
@Named("bars")
BarsDataSource(CollectionReference barsRef) {
    this.barsRef= barsRef;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's correct. There is no way for dagger2 to decide which one to provide, right ?

A possible solution is the usage of the `@Named` annotation. You will have to name them also at @Inject. EG.

```
@Named("users")
@Singleton
@Provides
static CollectionReference provideUsersCollRef(FirebaseFirestore db) {
    return db.collection("users");
}

@Named("bars")
@Singleton
@Provides
static CollectionReference provideBarsCollRef(FirebaseFirestore db) {
    return db.collection("bars");
}
```

and

```
 @Named("bars")
 @Inject
 public CollectionReference bars;
```

or with constructor injection

```
@Inject
BarsDataSource(@Named("bars") CollectionReference barsRef) {
    this.barsRef= barsRef;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I see now what can I name. But I'm injecting via constructor, how can I add the `@Named("bars")` there?

Comment: the same way. `@Named` can also be applied to constructor params

Comment: It dosn't work in the constructor the way you say. I get `error: @Qualifier annotations are not allowed on @Inject constructors` when using the code in my edited question.